# Find Parent of specific Child

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

Is it possible with the package xml.etree to find the parent of a child? For example:

```
<ELEMENTS>
    <CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION>
    </CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION>

</ELEMENTS>
<ELEMENTS>
    <DATA-SPECIFICATION>
    </DATA-SPECIFICATION>

</ELEMENTS>
```

I search for the object "ELEMENTS" that contains the Child "CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.//ELEMENTS[CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION]` *XPath expression*, example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ROOT>
        <ELEMENTS>
            <CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION>
            </CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION>

        </ELEMENTS>
        <ELEMENTS>
            <DATA-SPECIFICATION>
            </DATA-SPECIFICATION>

        </ELEMENTS>
</ROOT>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

print root.find('.//elements[constant-specification]')
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I get an Error "SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)"

Comment: @Peter are you sure you are executing the same exact code as posted?

Comment: Yes I am sure I copied it in an new *.py file

Comment: There is no syntax error. But `elements[constant-specification]` should be `ELEMENTS[CONSTANT-SPECIFICATION]`.